# How do you unlock bootloader on galaxy J3 (2016)

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow

I need it unlocked to move forward with customizing my device

Answer (score 1):

Go to Settings > Developers options >  OEM  unlock.

If the developer options is not enabled:

Go to Settings > About device > Software infos > Tape 7 times on Build number then go back to Settings the options should be visible now.

[image]

Comment: That doesn't actually unlock, it simply enables unlocking on some models.  Other models are locked down by the carrier for no reason.